# Homepage link to dashboard in Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

There is a link to the wordpress dashboard `<a href="/wp-admin">link</a>` on the homepage of my wordpress site and when the link is clicked it reloads the page with the url + `?login=failed` and does not take me to the dashboard.

When I type the url directly into the url bar adding /wp-admin it loads just fine. It only reloads with `?login=failed` when the link is used. Could this a problem with my wordpress configuration or is this something you can't do with wordpress in general?

**Additional info:**

The blog is on the root of the directory. e.g. http://www.example.com 
The links works correctly if the wordpress user is logged in.

Comment: Please add the code from your theme file - maybe it's something you're overlooking ... it could also be that there is something set explicitly in your theme's config or .htaccess, but let's start with the theme file.

Answer (score 1):

What is the full URL of your blog (you can use a false name)?

A forward slash is relative to root, so you might have domain.com/blog, in which case `href="/wp-admin"` will point to domain.com/wp-admin, instead of domain.com/blog/wp-admin

Your best bet is to use the WordPress admin URL constant in the href in your PHP file like so ...

```
<a href="<?php echo admin_url(); ?>">
```

... or use the site URL constant ...

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-admin">
```

... both should give the desired result.

Comment: So you don't have access to the theme files to try out the above?

Comment: Yes, I was able to add your links into the page through the wordpress editor but it still redirected to /?login=failed